# Shapes not moving on drawing panel java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

i am trying to make a simple java game with a bat(paddle) and ball. So far i have painted the 2 objects onto the panel, however i cant get them to move. i have added key events for the bat and a move() method for the ball. Below are all my classes.

Game class:

```
public class Game extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Game();
            }});
    }

    MyDrawingPanel myDrawingPanel = new MyDrawingPanel(this);
    MyUIPanel myUIPanel = new MyUIPanel(this);


    public Game()
    {
        setSize(1160,660); // you may change frame and panel sizes
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container cp = getContentPane();    
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cp.add(myDrawingPanel);
        cp.add(myUIPanel);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

MyDrawingPanel  class:

```
class MyDrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    Game game;

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Bat bat = new Bat(this);

    public MyDrawingPanel(Game game)
    {
        this.game=game;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);

        Graphics2D gBat = (Graphics2D) g;
        bat.paint(gBat);
    }
}
```

Ball class:

```
public class Ball {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xa = 1;
    int ya = 1;
    private MyDrawingPanel myDrawingPanel;

    public Ball(MyDrawingPanel myDrawingPanel) {
        this.myDrawingPanel = myDrawingPanel;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (x + xa < 0)
            xa = 1;
        if (x + xa > myDrawingPanel.getWidth() - 30)
            xa = -1;
        if (y + ya < 0)
            ya = 1;
        if (y + ya > myDrawingPanel.getHeight() - 30)
            ya = -1;

        x = x + xa;
        y = y + ya;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D  g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Bat class:

```
public class Bat{

    int x = 0;
    int xa = 0;
    private MyDrawingPanel myDrawingPanel;

    public Bat(MyDrawingPanel myDrawingPanel)
    {
        this.myDrawingPanel = myDrawingPanel;
    }

    public void move(){
        if(x + xa > 0 && x + xa <myDrawingPanel.getWidth()-60 )
            x = x + xa;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRoundRect(x, 500, 100, 20, 10, 10);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            xa = -1;
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            xa = 1;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        xa = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: For your panels you should be overriding `paintComponent` and calling `super.paintComponent` instead of `paint` and `super.paint`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, `Bat` _doesn't_ seem to be a component class, yet you're trying to `paint` and use `keyevents` in it.

Comment: hi people thanks for help, i am new to java so don't really know what to do so @peeskillet do i just change the method name and the super call of the existing paint methhod in the drawingpanel class. will this fix my problem?

Comment: Also, what exactly is `MyUIPanel`? I Don't see one anywhere

Comment: its just a panel with some buttons such as exit, new game, help. i didnt add this code in ask my buttons work

Comment: That won't fix your problem. for one, there is not `KeyListener` implementation. A method `keyPressed` does _absolutely nothing_ without an implementing `KeyListener` class

Comment: so do i have to impelememt the Keylistener in the bat class? also do i need to call the keylistenr/keypressed method of the bat class and the move method of the ball inside the drawingpanel class? im sorry to asks dumb questions @peeskillet

Comment: See my answer. That should get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Methods such as `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` don't do anything without a `KeyListener` implementation. So currently, your methods are useless. What you should do have the `DrawingPanel` class implement the `KeyListener`, like this

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    ...
}
```

The methods, `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` should be in that class.  You'll also want `setter` methods for what ever variables are updated in the `Bat` class, like `x` and `xa`, is those are the variables that determine the movement of the `Bat`.

So in the `keyPressed`, which should be in the `DrawingPanel` class, it could look something like this

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        bat.setXa(bat.getXa() - 1);
        repaint();
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        bat.setXa(1);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Notice how I call `repaint()`. That's what you need to do after you move something.

This should get you started in the right direction

---

## EDIT

**Forget the majority of the above answer.**

Instead of using a `KeyListener` though I would recommeng using key binding. You may face focus problems using `KeyListener`.  I implemented the keybinding for the `DrawingPanel` and it works fine.  It'll give you some ideas to work with.

```
class MyDrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    Game game;

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Bat bat = new Bat(this);

    public MyDrawingPanel(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        requestFocus();

        Action rightAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bat.x += 10;
                repaint();
            }
        };
        Action leftAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bat.x -= 10;
                repaint();
            }
        };

        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
        actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "leftAction");
        actionMap.put("leftAction", leftAction);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);

        Graphics2D gBat = (Graphics2D) g;
        bat.paint(gBat);
    }
}
```

---

See [How to use key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: so shall i take the kyepressed out of the bat class or is that neccessary aswell?

and do i need to add setter and getter methods or just setter in the bat class?

Comment: Yeah you don't need it

Comment: ok do i also need to remove the existing keyReleased from the bat class and also for my setter methods in the bat class do i have to pass it any parameters?

Comment: Take a look at my **EDIT**. Replace your `DrawingPanel` class with the one above. You'll see it work.

Comment: hi that has worked. Can it be done my way tho with key released and key pressed?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work because of some focus problems. That's why I used key bindings. `KeyListener` don't work too well with Swing. key bindings aren't too hard to work with. Just do whatever you need to do in the `actionPerformed`. And bind the key using the `InputMap` and `ActionMap`. I gave a link to a tutorial at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: ok is there any way to keep the bat from going of the screen? and for the ball how would i get that to move because that dosent require any key bindings is it just a call to the ball class from the drawing panel?

Comment: To get the ball to move you want to use a `javax.swing.Timer`. That's another question you should ask. And the bat not to move off the screen just add an `if` statement to check the location of the bat